# Azure. Release not getting triggered and stucks when triggered manually

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-deployment

I'm using Azure DevOps to build and release my web app. I'm facing the following issue now: 
after the code push the build started and completed successfully, but then the release didn't get triggered. And when I started it manually it got stuck with the issue I was unable to google:

```
Circuit Breaker "HttpClientThrottler-LocationHttpClient-tfsprodweu3.visualstudio.com" short-circuited. In the last 10000 milliseconds, there were: 1 failure, 0 timeout, 95 short circuited, 0 concurrency rejected, and 0 limit rejected. Last exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException A task was canceled.
```

The previous commit was built and released automatically without any issues. Only thing I've changed in azure configs - enabled the WebSockets (p.s. after that the release was also successful)

here is the screenshot:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: I'm getting similar issues right now. I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's fall out of the outage they had this morning. maybe the VM's processing these requests are just dealing with the backlog but I'm not 100% on this.

Comment: Can you please add the image to the post instead of linking? This way it is easier to view. In addition some corporate firewalls block Imgur so you will be more likely to get help. (If the screenshot is code please consider pasting it into the answer.)

Comment: @CaptainMan, sorry for the stupid question, but...how to embed an image into a post? As far as I remember it used to be possible to simply paste an image, but I was not able at this time...I had to sign up to the imgur :D

Comment: @NikitaFedorov There is a button on the edit screen that looks like a photo of a mountain with a sun. 6th from the left. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the same issue. It's likely not a problem incurred by you.
Our releasechain is unchanged and worked fine last night. 
The issue has been reported on [developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/440514/unable-to-deploy-circuit-breaker-httpclientthrottl.html) and being upvoted quickly.

Update1: Microsoft just [posted](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/440697/view.html) they are working on the problem.

Update2: The issue appeared as an [active event](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/102475253) on [Azure status history](https://status.dev.azure.com/)

Update3: Though the [active event](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/102475253) is still listed, I managed to deploy my release just now. Hope this works for everyone else too now. Might be necessary for some project to wait till the [active event](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/102475253) is officially marked ok.

Comment: yes, now I'm able to deploy, thanks for the information